# What is the most efficient way to read integer 2D array with unknown size from .txt file?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, txt

In **read.txt** file I have:

//start of read.txt

The first matrix is:
1, 2, 3, 4;
5, 6, 7, 8;
9, 8, 1, 2;\

//end of read.txt

Notice spaces, commas, and semicolons
**The matrix can be different!** (thats why I wrote matrix with unknown size)

**My very very inefficient approach:**
using `getline(File, string)` and `while(getline(File,str))` loop I will go through the loop for the **first** time to find rows and columns. Then I will use rows and columns to create `int arr[row][col]`, and go through the **second** loop and the same file to assign each integer to `arr[row][col]`. 
I was also considering `malloc()`, however, it erases arrays content every time when I allocate new memory(for example in order to create more rows).

My method above is very slow and messy. So I'm looking for advice how to make it more efficient!

Comment: You tagged C++, so forget about `malloc()`. And if number of columns is fixed, use `std::array`, else `std::vector`.

Comment: If you use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) instead of `malloc`, the problem of losing the previously filled array contents will be solved. However, as already pointed out by someone else, in C++, you can simply use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the resizing of the underlying memory buffer will be handled for you automatically.

Comment: Description is written in such way that it suggest that `The first matrix is:` is part of the file. Use code tags to mark range of file so there is no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the correct approach to solve that problem.

If you want to store unknown number of columns, then you can use a `std::vector`. It will grow dynamically, as you like.

And if you want to store an unknown number of rows with columns in it, then you will use again a `std::vector`. But at this time a vector of vector, So, a 2 dimensional vector: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`.

This will store any number of rows with any number of different columns.

Next. To extract the data from a line, or better said, split the line.

There is a special dedicated iterator for this. The `std::sregex_token_iterator`. You may define a pattern on what you are looking for. Or, you may define a pattern, what you are not looking for, the separator.

And since regexes are very versatile, you can build complex patterns that fit your needs.

For positively sarach digits you can use R"(\d+)", for negative search separators you could use R"([\.;\\])".

If you want to to search for separators, then you can add a -1 as last parameter to the constructor.

To get the result of the split of the line, we will use the `std::vector`s range constructor. Here you can specify a start iterator and an end iterator and the constructor, together with the `std::sregex_token_iterator` will do all work for you.

See the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using Columns = std::vector<std::string>;
using Rows = std::vector<Columns>;

const std::string fileName{ "data.txt" };
const std::regex re{ R"(\d+)" };

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputFileStream{ fileName }; inputFileStream) {

        // Here we will store the result
        Rows rows{};

        // Read all complete text lines from text file
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(inputFileStream, line);) {

            // Get the columns
            Columns columns(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re), {});

            // Add the columns to rows
            rows.push_back(columns);
        }
        // Debug Ouput
        for (const auto& row : rows) {
            for (const auto& column : row) std::cout << column << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

       
    } // Error message, if file could not be opened
    else std::cerr << "\nError:Could not open file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

To be compiled with C++17

Answer (score -1):

On a Linux operating system you could use [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to see your textual file in your address space, and later use standard parsing techniques, maybe [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

I believe the performance won't change a lot: most of the time would be spent in doing the IO (e.g. waiting for the rotating disk, if you have one). Unless you have to parse a huge matrix (e/g. many million integers) I believe your approach is good enough in practice in 2021.

I recommend using a profiler (e.g. [GNU gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/)) before making any reengineering decisions. It is likely that the CPU time would be spent elsewhere in your program.

You may want to study for inspiration the source code of existing open  source programs with some parsing, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [fish](https://fishshell.com/).

Of course, read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and use [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

You could use partial evaluation techniques and generate machine code at runtime with [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) suited to the particular size of your matrix. I believe it is not worth the effort.

### I recommend to write a fully correct program first, debug it, and only later optimize it.

Consider using static analyzers like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com).

Comment: Do any of your answers or comments not have a link to refpersys?

Comment: I linked to other open ourse programs doing parsing.

Comment: And yes, I do mention programs I have co:m!mpiled or contributed to.